# Can I print lists from the Reminders app?

Tags: macos, printing, reminders

I would like to print out the lists and tasks that I maintain in the **Reminders** app.

I can copy the text or take screenshots and paste them to a program like Word, but… Is there an easier approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this using AppleScript on your Mac. Press <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> <kbd>space</kbd> and enter `Script Editor`. Create a new script with the following code in it:

```
set _body to ""
tell application "Reminders"
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "\n"
    set _body to (name of reminders in list "Tasks" whose completed is false) as string
end tell

set _output to "Macintosh HD:Users:YourName:Desktop:List.txt"
try
    set _reference to open for access file _output with write permission
    write _body to _reference
    close access _reference
on error
    try
        close access file _output
    end try
end try
```

Replace `Tasks` with the name of the list you want to print, `Macintosh HD` with the name of your startup drive, and `YourName` with your username.

This will place a file named `List.txt` on your desktop with all those reminders ready to print.

Comment: This is a lifesaver.  Thank you so much!  I had compiled a Reminders list with 392 long items, and dreaded the copy/paste effort almost as much as the thought of accidentally deleting the whole list.  Perhaps worth noting: the script will not overwrite an existing file, and will not automatically create a file with a name like "List - Copy 1.txt".  Also, I added an extra carriage return between the quotes after 'text item delimiters' to double-space between the items in my outputted txt file.  Again: THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

On the iPhone/iPad, [CalPrint](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/calprint-for-iphone/id385149531?mt=8&at=1001lwpF) ([iPad](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/calprint/id400413694?mt=8&at=1001lwpF)) does this